# jquery filter selector won't match

Tags: jquery, filter, selector

I am getting frustrated over a simple problem where I cannot find the issue:

I want to filter rows from a table by looking for any cells having been marked as "filtered" because of different criteria. So a final row filtering kind of "selects" the filtered cells to decide if the containing row is to be filtered.

Here is the simplyfied example:

html:

```
<table>   <tbody>
    <tr class="">
        <td class=""><span>1-1</span></td>
        <td class=""><span>1-2</span></td>
        <td class=""><span>1-3</span></td>      
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
        <td class=""><span>2-1</span></td>
        <td class="filtered"><span>2-2</span></td>
        <td class="filtered"><span>2-3</span></td>      
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
        <td class=""><span>3-1</span></td>
        <td class="filtered"><span>3-2</span></td>
        <td class=""><span>3-3</span></td>      
    </tr>   </tbody> </table>
```

​css:

```
table { margin: 20px; }
td { padding:4px; }
td span { background-color: silver; }
tr.filtered { display:none; }​
```

js/jquery:

```
$('table tbody tr').filter('td.filtered').addClass('filtered');
```

I prepared a fiddler for this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/dtsZX/3/

I would expect rows 2 and 3 to get the class "filtered" added, thus being hidden. 
However that does not work. 
What is wrong with the jquery command ?

Comment: `console.log($('table tbody tr').filter('td.filtered'));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `:has`:

```
$('table tbody tr:has(td.filtered)').addClass('filtered');
```

The `tr`s themselves can never match `td`! Instead, you want to filter `tr`s *that have a `td` as their descendant*.

Comment: Interesting, this is what I expected from intuition. But some hour ago I read in a discussion that such ':has' selector would be a fine thing but won't get implemented since it would mean horrible performance implications.
Works like charm and is easy to read. Thanks.

Comment: @arkascha: Basically, `:has` is not implemented by the browser but purely in jQuery. That generally means slower execution, but I would really test whether the performance decrease of your app is noticeable instead of abandoning it right away.

Comment: Ok, I understand, that makes sense. 
I did not abondon because of the performance, but because I was convinced that it was not implemented. The discussion was about a css pseudo selector, s I realize now :-)

Comment: @arkascha: Ah OK, well, if `:has` existed in CSS you could just add the class through CSS anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add "filtered" to the tr:

```
$('table tbody tr').find("td.filtered").parent().addClass("filtered")
```

instead of:

```
$('table tbody tr').filter('td.filtered').addClass('filtered');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dtsZX/7/

Comment: I clearly stated that I want to hide the rows which contain cells marked as "filtered".

Answer (score 1):

The filter method does not work in this way. See [the JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Filter actually returns the items chosen in the previous selector which **also** match the the selector in the `filter` method.

Try using this: `$('table tbody tr td.filtered').parent().addClass('filtered');`

or the `:has` selector as mentioned by another answerer (if using jQuery 1.1.4 or above).